# Cannot start apache in xampp; unexpected shutdown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, xampp

I can't start apache in xampp:

```
Status change detected: stopped
    12:23:32  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
    12:23:32  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    12:23:32  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    12:23:32  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    12:23:32  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    12:23:32  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
    12:23:32  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ports or set apache listen another port.
Hope it is help.